# Is there a name for this anime/manga visual convention?

Tags: tropes

sometimes when a character is frustrated or has failed to do something, a cloud made of moving squiggly lines will form above their head (it's somewhat of a common trope in video games that use speech bubbles too.)

[image: eden of the east]

Is there a name for this anime/manga visual convention?

Comment: Pretty sure I've also seen this in some Western comics, too (though I can't think of any to support this claim).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this pictorial rune has the name: *twirl*.

These *pictorial rune's* originate from Forceville's categorization, which mostly describes the location/orientation.

[image]

This is often used to depict movement as well as confusion, as described by [samcyb](http://samcyb-uniwork-unit2.blogspot.nl/2015/12/entry-2-anger-research.html)
[image]

<sub>Forcevile Image source: [source](http://www.academia.edu/33714509/Pictorial_runes_and_emotions_in_comics_an_experimental_study)</sub>